# Click function takes no effect

Tags: python, selenium, click

I use python 3.9.5 and selenium 4.1.0 with microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.43 on Windows 10  and operations like below when I have to click in something at the page does not works.

```
#element is the web element I want to fill
element = "element_name"
date = driver.find_element(By.ID, element)

date.click()
```

I figure out to solve this with below code but it is not the ideal and genarates some other problems.

```
webelement.WebElement.click = lambda self : driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", self)
```

Any hint of how to solve this question? Is it a Bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't share a link to the page you are working on and not shared all your code we can only guess.
So, there are several thing that can be wrong here:
1)
You are missing a wait.
It so, instead of

```py
#element is the web element I want to fill
element = "element_name"
date = driver.find_element(By.ID, element)

date.click()
```

Try using this

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_name")).click()
```

To do so you need the following imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

2. 

The element can be out of the visible screen.
If so, you will need to scroll the element into the view as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
element = "element_name"
date = driver.find_element(By.ID, element)
actions.move_to_element(date).perform()
driver.find_element(By.ID, element).click()
```

There are more possible issues, however to know what is the problem in your case we need more details